# How to disable the Cross Stack creation of outputs and imports when sharing tokens accross stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am working on two separate stacks (call them A and B) in the same CDK project.  I generate a policy in stack B containing resource references to the ARNs of resources in stack A.  CDK does this smart bit of magic that creates CfnOutputs for each of the arns shared and then uses Fn::ImportValue in stack B.

Sample TypeScript code in stack B:

```
const role = stackA.role;
stackB.permissionsBoundary.addStatements(
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
          resources: [ role.roleArn ],
          actions: [
            'sts:AssumeRole'
          ]
        })
      );
```

I do not want it to do this.  It causes all kinds of grief when you need to dispose of the stacks afterwards.  I just want to use literal strings in stack B that are extracted from the tokens generated in Stack A.

Please tell me there is a way to turn off this feature.  It is a very, very leaky abstraction and should be optional.

Example generated template in Stack A:

```
"ExportsOutputFnGetAttfoo": {
      "Value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "bar",
          "Arn"
        ]
      },
      "Export": {
        "Name": "stackA:ExportsOutputFnGetAttfoo"
      }
    }
```

Example generated template in Stack B:

```
"Resource": [
  {
    "Fn::ImportValue": "stackA:ExportsOutputFnGetAttfoo"
  }
```

Comment: Second to this. My stack automatically exports `DnsEntries`, which is a list, which fails the stack. Why not let us control the export, or we can simply use variables right?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to use

> literal strings in stack B that are extracted from the tokens generated in Stack A.

as the ARNs are not known at the CloudFormation template generation time since you generate the both stacks at the same time.

Cross-stack resource sharing via CF outputs is the usual method to use - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html